# Looker's Date Granularity Filter

Tags: looker

Currently, in a Looker's Look, I can only select the granularity (e.g. Date, Month, Year) under the dimension. However, assuming that I'm on Date now, if I want to change it to Year, I will have to edit the Look and change it manually.

Is there a way to change the granularity using a filter?

I'm operating three separate Looks, one for Date, one for Month and the other Year. It seems rather inefficient to manage three Looks. I would assume changing granularity is a basic function.